# How to use like function in MySQL or run LIKE command in mysql when search need to more specific

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sql-like, puzzle

I want to search in database that how much person have name 'i am steven'

I want to search on user table with their three column

firstname
secondname
lastname

I want to sorting them as First name match comes first secondname latter and lastname last when I see the result.

are their any command in mysql solve this puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
if (firstname    like 'i am steven%', 4,
  if(secondname  like 'i am steven%', 2,
    if (lastname like 'i am steven%', 1, 0)
  )
) as first_name_first
from 
 user
where 
  firstname  like 'i am steven%' or
  secondname like 'i am steven%' or
  lastname   like 'i am steven%'
order by first_name_first desc;
```

Comment: well tell me why are you put 4, 2, 1 and what is significance of them here in commands

Comment: `3,2,1` also can, what it mean is to give a heavy weight for firstname matches, followed by secondname, and lastname. So, if matches on firstname, it will displayed first